# ¿El bloque finally se ejecuta siempre en Java?

Tags: java, try-catch

Tengo un try/catch con un return adentro. ¿Se ejecutará el bloque finally?

```
try {  
    something();  
    return success;  
}  
catch (Exception e) {   
    return failure;  
}  
finally {  
    System.out.println("No se si esto se va a imprimir.");
}
```

Yo se que puedo escribir esto y ver que pasa (Que es realmente lo que voy a hacer) pero cuando lo busquè en google, nada apareció, entonces hice la pregunta aquí.

Esta es una pregunta traducida del original en ingés y adaptada a los resultados que da en mi ordenador : [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java) de [jonny five](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885027/jonny-five)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**finally** será llamado.

Las unicas veces que finally no se ejecutará serán cuando:

1. si tu llamas System.exit() ó
2. si el jvm tiene un fallo primero(crashes)

Esta respuesta es una traducción [del original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java) de [jodonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223/jodonnell)

Editado 12/2/15: Tomando en cuenta [Does the finally block execute if the thread running the function is interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576765/does-the-finally-block-execute-if-the-thread-running-the-function-is-interrupted) de [Subhrajyoti Majumder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209513/subhrajyoti-majumder)

Comment: no tengo muy claro esto de copiar preguntas y respondertelas, pero ya que te pones podrías copiar la respuesta "mejorada". En un comentario se aclaró que `interrupt()` no evita que se ejecute el finally, sólo los métodos en desuso de `stop()` o `suspend()` sin llamar a `resume()`. Copiado del [comentario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/1803874) de [Christian Semrau](http://stackoverflow.com/users/282229/christian-semrau)

Comment: Hay muchos más casos en que no se ejecuta el bloque finally. La jvm es abortada por agentes externos (kill). Se apaga el ordenador. Bucle infinito dentro del try.

Answer (score 8):

Una pregunta muy sencilla basada en principios de java, el bloque **finally** siempre será llamado.

```
try {
    //Declaraciones que pueden causar una excepción.
}
catch {
   //Manejo de excepción.
}
finally {
   //Declaraciones a ser ejecutadas
}
```

Siempre y cuando como se comenta, termines la ejecución del código o existan errores.

Más información :**[The Finally Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)**

Answer (score 7):

## NO SIEMPRE

La especificación del lenguaje de Java describe cómo funcionan los bloques try-catch-finally y try-finally en el apartado [14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).
En ningún lugar especifica que finally se ejecute siempre.
Pero sí especifica que para todos los casos en que el bloque try-catch-finally o try-finally se completa antes se tiene que haber ejecutado el bloque finally.

Es decir. Si *SIG* es lo que se ejecutará después del bloque try-catch-finally o try-finally y *FIN* es lo que hay dentro de finally, la JLS garantiza que ***FIN* se ejecuta siempre antes de que se ejecute *SIG*.**

¿Por qué la JLS no garantiza que el bloque finally se ejecuta siempre tras el bloque try? Porque es imposible. Es improbable pero posible que la máquina virtual sea abortada (kill, crash, apagar ordenador) justo tras finalizar el bloque try y antes de que se ejecute el bloque finally. Y no hay nada que se pueda hacer desde la especificación del lenguaje para evitar esto.

Answer (score -1):

Dentro de un bloque `try / catch` `finally` siempre se ejecuta, como dice la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> El bloque finally siempre se ejecuta cuando sale el bloque `try`. Esto
>   garantiza que el bloque `finally` se ejecute incluso si se produce una
>   excepción inesperada. Pero, finalmente, es útil para algo más que el
>   manejo de excepciones: permite al programador evitar que el código de
>   limpieza se desvíe accidentalmente por una devolución, una
>   continuación o una interrupción. **Poner código de limpieza en un bloque
>   `finally` siempre es una buena práctica**, incluso cuando no se prevén
>   excepciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Si la JVM sale mientras se está ejecutando el código try o catch, entonces el bloque finally **no se puede ejecutar**. Del mismo modo, si el hilo que ejecuta el código `try` o `catch` **es interrumpido o eliminado, el bloque finally no puede ejecutarse aunque la aplicación en su conjunto continúe**.

### A partir de Java SE 7 `finally` perdió protagonismo

Antes de Java SE 7 se podía implementar el uso de `finally` como una **herramienta clave para evitar fugas de recursos**. Al cerrar un archivo o recuperar recursos, se recomendaba colocar  el código en un bloque `finally` para asegurarse de que el recurso siempre se recuperará o se cerrará.

Ya que `finally` siempre se ejecuta, independientemente de si la instrucción `try` se completa normalmente o abruptamente, `finally` era la único opción posible para asegurarse de que un recurso sería *finalmente*  cerrado.

Esto lo vemos en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
//Otro uso de finally antes de Java SE 7
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
                                                     throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}
```

Antes de Java 7 `finally`nos ayudaba a ir dejando el terreno limpio de todos los recursos abiertos.

### A partir de Java 7 se implementó el try-with-resources Statement

La sentencia [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) es una sentencia `try` que declara uno o más recursos. **Un recurso es un objeto que debe cerrarse una vez finalizado el programa**. La instrucción try-with-resources asegura que cada recurso se cierre al final de la sentencia. Cualquier objeto que implemente `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, que incluye todos los objetos que implementan `java.io.Closeable`, se puede utilizar como un recurso.

En el ejemplo siguiente se lee la primera línea de un archivo. Utiliza una instancia de `BufferedReader` para leer datos del archivo. `BufferedReader` es un recurso que debe cerrarse una vez finalizado el programa:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, el recurso declarado en la instrucción `try-with-resources` es un `BufferedReader`. La sentencia de declaración aparece entre paréntesis inmediatamente después de la palabra clave `try`. La clase `BufferedReader`, en Java SE 7 y posteriores, implementa la interfaz `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Dado que la instancia `BufferedReader` se declara en una sentencia `try-with-resources`, **se cerrará independientemente de si la sentencia try se completa normalmente o abruptamente** (como resultado del método `BufferedReader.readLine` que arroja una `IOException`).