# Hibernate NullPointerException al ejecutar session.close();

Tags: java, hibernate

Muy buenas, estoy usando hibernate por primera vez y estoy tratando de hacer una sencilla aplicación en la que ahora me salta un error que no sé que pueda significar. He seguido una serie de tutoriales en los que me explicaban como configurar todo y hasta ahora todo habia ido bien, he podido ejecutar selects, inserts y deletes sin problemas, pero de un momento para acá me empezó a dar problemas con cualquier operación que quisiera ejecutar.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-A1M7E3R:1433;databaseName=Agencia</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="Models/Avion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Sucursal.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Vuelo.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Cliente.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Hotel.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Clase.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Reservacion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Habitacion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Models/Tipo.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="Agencia"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Habitacion"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Clase"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Reservacion"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Avion"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Tipo"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Hotel"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Sucursal"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Vuelo"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Cliente"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**ClienteDAO.java**

```
package DAO;

import Models.Cliente;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
 *
 * @author GerardoAGL
 */
public class ClienteDAO {

    private Session sesion;
    private Transaction tx;

    public int guardar(Cliente cliente) {
        int id = 0;

        try{
            iniciaOperacion();
            id = (int) sesion.save(cliente);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            manejaExcepcion(e);
        }finally{
            sesion.close();
        }

        return id;
    }

    public List<Cliente> buscar(String busqueda) {

        List<Cliente> clientes = null;
        String sql ="FROM Cliente WHERE "
                + "nombre LIKE '%"+busqueda+"%' OR "
                + "apellido LIKE '%"+busqueda+"%' OR "
                + "cedula LIKE '%"+busqueda+"%'";

        try{
            iniciaOperacion();
            clientes = sesion.createQuery(sql).list();
        }finally{
            sesion.close();
        }

        return clientes;
    }

    public void eliminar(Cliente cliente) {
        try{
            iniciaOperacion();
            sesion.delete(cliente);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            manejaExcepcion(e);
        }finally{
            sesion.close();
        }
    }

    private void iniciaOperacion() throws HibernateException{

        sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void manejaExcepcion(HibernateException e) throws HibernateException {

        tx.rollback();
        throw new HibernateException("Ocurrió un error en la capa de acceso a datos", e);
    } 
}
```

**Este es el error que tengo**

```
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
sep 03, 2017 11:20:03 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
sep 03, 2017 11:20:03 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DAO.ClienteDAO.guardar(ClienteDAO.java:33)
    at Controllers.CreateClientController.guardarCliente(CreateClientController.java:67)
    at Controllers.CreateClientController.actionPerformed(CreateClientController.java:44)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

La linea que me causa el problema, de la clase ClienteDAO es la siguiente

[image: Linea de codigo del error]

Gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el bloque `finally` en Java se va a ejecutar así lances una excepción desde el `catch`, tal como se explica en [¿El bloque finally se ejecuta siempre en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162/227) (incluye los casos donde no se ejecuta). Esto significa que tu variable `session` no fue inicializada debido a algún problema y su valor es `null`, por ende al llamar a `session.close()` se lanza la excepción.

La forma de arreglar tu código, por el diseño actual, sería:

```
//en tus métodos, invocar el siguiente método
finally {
    cerrarSesion(session);
}

//agregar el siguiente método que asegura que no haya problemas
private void cerrarSession(Session session) {
    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo !! añadí eso que me dijiste y me seguia saliendo error, pero ahora la consola me era mas especifica en señalarme el error jaja. Resulta que en uno de los modelos tenia un atributo con el nombre mal escrito. Me salvaste la vida hermano :D